# Getting vimeo webpage using curl

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm trying to get webpage of vimeo video using curl but I'm getting `http-code 301`. I also added `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` but I'm not getting anything.

Here's my code, why isn't it working?

```
function getremote($url) {
    $agent="spider";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
    $html=curl_exec($ch);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;
}
$json_errors=array();
$ul="vimeo.com/124182657";;
$content=getremote($ul);
```

Comment: I edited your code into the question, please make sure that it looks right in case something has been lost in translation.

Comment: It's right pls tell me solution

Comment: I don't know PHP, but hopefully now someone who does can help you.